# Spring security repeated redirects

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring security in my application. I want the user to be logged in first before accessing any pages on the server, hence i am taking the redirect approach. But the redirect seems to be in an infinite loop cause it redirects me to the login page no matter how many times i submit the page. I tried debugging and the request always hits the GET instead of the POST method as i expected. I am using LDAP authentication using the details entered by the user on the form. Here is the code in the security context xml . Can someone point me in the right direction.

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/dashboard"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

When i remove the 
**`<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/dashboard"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />`** 
it defaults to spring login page and it works but i have to use the user credentials from the configuration xml as opposed to LDAP credentials.

Edit**

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="${contextPath}/resources/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
 <h2 style="text-align:center">Login to continue to Application</h2>
<div align="center" class="div">
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="login" action="authenticate">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="username" class="label">Username:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="username" class="input"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="username" class="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password" class="label">Password:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:password path="password" class="input"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="password" class="error"/></td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit"
                    value="Login" class="button"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

thanks
Sree

Comment: can you share your custom login page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Finally i got to a working state. Here are the changes i made to the security context xml

```
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
```

the url regex change. And also the action in my login.jsp is now

```
action="/login/authenticate"
```

and finally the controller request mapping path is updated.
Hope this helps anyone who has a similar issue. I am yet to discover if this is the right approach to achieve it but works for now.

-Sree

Answer (score 0):

@sri

as mentioned in your code i can see that you have intercepted the URL `"/login*"`

now any url with login at the end will be intercepted by spring security and after that you have to put the correct credentials....

now After giving credentials your are redirected to page `/login`

now its clear that again our url is ending with login hence it is intercepted again by spring security ...
thats why the loop continues....

**Possible Solution**

this may work for you,
just put the following code below `<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />` tag as shown:

**code:**

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/Login.html" security="none" />
```

Comment: @sri  tell me if there is some problem

Comment: the POST on the login jsp takes to a different url not /login. Anyway i tried your suggestion but didn't work.